# With jquery moving one table column to a new table

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is take the last colomn in a table placed into a new table altogether. I got this working the problem is I want this to work for multiple tables with the same class names. Right now it only takes the first tables cols and repeats them. I have an idea of why but I am not sure how to target each table as an individual element even though they all have the same class name.

jquery

```
function fixLastColumn() {                
// makes new table 
     var nt = $('<table class="ft_fixedTable"></table>');

     $(".ft_FixedTable tr").each(function(i) { 
        nt.append('<tr class="ft_fixTR"><td class="ft_fixTD">'+$(this).children('td:last').html()+'</td></tr>')
     })
    nt.appendTo('.fixedDiv');

    // remove last column
    $('.ft_FixedTable tr').each(function(i) {
   $(this).children('td:last').remove();
     });
   }

$(document).ready(function() {
    fixLastColumn();
 });
```

html

```
<table class="ft_FixedTable">
    <thead> 
        <tr>
        <td>Title 1</td>
        <td class="ft_fixedCol">fixed one</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Content Content Content Content Content</td>
    <td>Fixed content </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div class="fixedDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to move the table cells themselves instead of just copying the contents:

```
function fixLastColumn() {
    // makes new table 
    var nt = $('<table id="ft_fixedTable_2" />');

    $(".ft_FixedTable tr").each(function(i) {
        $('<tr class="ft_fixTR"/>')
            .append($(this).children('td:last'))
            .appendTo(nt);
    })
    nt.appendTo('.fixedDiv');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    fixLastColumn();
});
```

As a (small but potentially significant) optimization, however, you should use IDs instead of classes to identify your tables and divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/TVpHp/

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what i was trying to do :) I am very new to this so I'm still trying to figure out what it is I'm doing and how this actually works. I think i get it.

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with the fact that you're selecting `ft_FixedTable` but the class your assigning the new table is `ft_fixedTable`. Notice the lower cased `f`.

---

Is this what you're going for? http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/NzbHs/

Comment: Not quite but thank you for your reply. I m a bit of a novice at this :(

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ft_FixedTable").each(function() {
  var $last = $("td:last", this).remove();

  $('<table class="ft_fixedTable"></table>')
  .append('<tr class="ft_fixTR"><td class="ft_fixTD">' 
          + $last.html() 
          + '</td></tr>'
  )
  .appendTo('.fixedDiv');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the `.each()` method only works on the first item of the selector, in this case, the first table with the `ft_FixedTable` class. You could try doing it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ft_FixedTable').each(function () {
        var index = $('tr td:last', this).index();
        $('tr td', this).eq(index).remove();
    });
});
```

This will find the last column index and remove that `td` from all the rows inside the current table.

Comment: What i was trying to do is select the first table (table A) then removed the last col, add it to a new table (table B) then move on to the next (table A) etc.. Although my crappy skills made me spend the day trying to figure out a way to do this :(